# Finding the max of each continguous subarray of a given size

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, queue

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Python

> Given an array and an integer k, find the maximum for each and every contiguous subarray of size k.

The idea is to use a double ended queue. This is my code:

```
def diff_sliding_window(arr, win):
#     max = -inf
    Q = []
    win_maxes = [] # max of each window
    for i in range(win):
        print(Q)
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[len(Q) - 1]:
            # get rid of the index of the smaller element
            Q.pop() # removes last element
        Q.append(i)
#     print('>>', Q)

    for i in range(win, len(arr)):
#         win_maxes.append(arr[Q[0]])
        print(arr[Q[0]])
        while len(Q) > 0 and Q[0] <= i - win:
            Q.pop()
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[len(Q)-1]:
            Q.pop(0)
        Q.append(i)
#     win_maxes.append(arr[Q[0]])

    print(arr[Q[0]])
```

But I can't figure out why for the test cases:

```
t1 = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
t2 = [12, 1, 78, 90, 57, 89, 56]
```

that I'm not getting the correct results.

---

**Update**:

I've made the changes that Matt Timmermans suggested, but I'm still not obtaining the proper output. For `t2`, and `win = 3`

```
78
90
90
89 <--- should be 90
89
```

Here is my updated code:

```
from collections import deque

def diff_sliding_window(arr, win):
#     max = -inf
    Q = deque()
    win_maxes = [] # max of each window
    for i in range(win):
#         print(Q)
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[Q[len(Q)-1]]:
            # get rid of the index of the smaller element
            Q.pop() # removes last element
        Q.append(i)
#     print('>>', Q)

    for i in range(win, len(arr)):
#         win_maxes.append(arr[Q[0]])
        print(arr[Q[0]])
        while len(Q) > 0 and Q[0] <= i - win:
            Q.pop()
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[Q[len(Q)-1]]:
            Q.popleft()
        Q.append(i)


    print(arr[Q[0]])
```

Comment: `collections.deque` is an efficient structure for pushing and popping values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement the O(n) algorithm for this problem, which would be better than the other two answers here at this time.

But, your implementation is incorrect.  Where you say `arr[i] >= arr[len(Q)-1]`, you *should* say `arr[i] >= arr[Q[len(Q)-1]]` or `arr[i] >= arr[Q[-1]]`.  You also swapped the `pop` and `pop(0)` cases in the second loop.  It looks like it will be correct after you fix those.

Also, though, your algorithm is not O(n), because you using `Q.pop(0)`, which takes O(k) time.  Your total running time is therefore O(kn) instead.  Using a deque for `Q` will fix this.

Here it is all fixed, with some comments to show how it works:

```
from collections import deque

def diff_sliding_window(arr, win):

    if win > len(arr):
        return []

    win_maxes = [] # max of each window

    #Q contains indexes of items in the window that are greater than
    #all items to the right of them.  This always includes the last item
    #in the window
    Q = deque()

    #fill Q for initial window
    for i in range(win):
        #remove anything that isn't greater than the new item
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[Q[-1]]:
            Q.pop()
        Q.append(i)

    win_maxes.append(arr[Q[0]])

    for i in range(win, len(arr)):
        #remove indexes (at most 1, really) left of window
        while len(Q) > 0 and Q[0] <= (i-win):
            Q.popleft()

        #remove anything that isn't greater than the new item
        while len(Q) > 0 and arr[i] >= arr[Q[-1]]:
            Q.pop()
        Q.append(i)
        win_maxes.append(arr[Q[0]])

    return win_maxes
```

try it: https://ideone.com/kQ1qsQ

Proof that this is O(N):  Each iteration of the inner loops removes an item from Q.  Since there are only `len(arr)` added to Q in total, there can be at most `len(arr)` *total* iterations of the inner loops.

Comment: I made the update that you recommended, but am still not getting the correct output. Also, why does Q.pop(0) on a list have O(k) time? Shouldn't it be O(1) if you know the index of the list?

Comment: @AlanH Elements of a python array are stored contiguously in memory, with any empty left-over space at the end.  When you `pop(0)`, all of the elements in positions `1` thorough `len(Q)` are moved up to fill the empty space at the beginning.  When you `pop()` the end, however, the empty space is created at the end where it belongs, so nothing needs to be moved.

Comment: I amended your suggested corrections, but for some reason was still unable to get the correct answer. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @AlanH  yup, there was another bug.  I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach (which only needs one pass over the data):

#### Code

```
def calc(xs, k):
    k_max = []
    result = []

    for ind, val in enumerate(xs):
        # update local maxes (all are active)
        for i in range(len(k_max)):
            if val > k_max[i] :
                k_max[i] = val
        # one new sub-array starts
        k_max.append(val)

        if ind >= (k-1):  # one sub-array ends
            result.append(k_max[0])
            k_max.pop(0)

    return result

t1 = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
t2 = [12, 1, 78, 90, 57, 89, 56]
print(calc(t1, 3))
print(calc(t2, 2))
```

#### Output

```
[3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
[12, 78, 90, 90, 89, 89]
```

Comment: Was the 'one pass' comment added in reference to my solution? `itertools.tee` may require auxiliary storage (very little with sliding windows) but is efficient. Timings has it about 30%-50% faster.

Comment: @AChampion I sure hope it is, because i'm not using the right data-structures (= very unoptimized code using arrays in ```result``` and especially ```k_max```). Don't get me wrong, i love functional-programming and itertools. But sometimes something else is a bit easier to grasp. Nonetheless: nice code!

Comment: `collections.deque` certainly does improve things slightly. Thanks, you build up a set of iter/functional utils so `nwise` was just pulled off the shelf - and was just an extension of `pairwise` from the `itertools` recipes.

Comment: @AChampion I'm not that motivated to optimize this. But very great remark about collections.deque (as it's specialized exactly for the two operations my code needs)! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `itertools` and `tee`:

```
def nwise(iterable, n):
    ''' Step through the iterable in groups of n '''
    ts = it.tee(iterable, n)
    for c, t in enumerate(ts):
        next(it.islice(t, c, c), None)
    return zip(*ts)

def max_slide(ns, l):
    return [max(a) for a in nwise(ns, l)]

>>> max_slide([1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7], 3)
[3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
>>> max_slide([12, 1, 78, 90, 57, 89, 56], 3)
[78, 90, 90, 90, 89]
```